# When I use the cog and go to shutdown all I lose is the menu

Tags: 11.10, gui, shutdown, power-cog

I would like to know the procedure of the GUI shutdown from the cog. This is because I have one 11.10 that will shutdown from the cog and shutdown button but, I have another that if I use the cog and the shutdown button I only loose the side menu.  The background stays and the computer will not shut off. I want to learn how the GUI process for shutdown works so I can learn and compare the two. I have googled for two days with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The command that should be run when it's clicked seems to be: 
`qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout 0 2 2`

See if that works on its own? If not, something's likely wrong with your dbus.